# Does calling another method inside an overridden method violate " depending upon abstractions"?

Tags: oop

I have an interface `IPrintSomething` with a method `print()`.

I have a class called `Printer` which implements the `IPrintSomething` interface.

Let's say class `Printer` has another method called `doTheActualPrinting()`
If I call `doTheActualPrinting()` inside the `print()` method, does that mean that class `Printer` already knows how to print? Does this make it no longer dependent on the abstraction `IPrintSomething`?

Comment: Why can't the code of `doTheActualPrinting()` be inside the `Printer` class's `print()` method? Does the `doTheActualPrinting()` have another purpose?

Comment: Yes, that is possible but in this case, let's assume I want to print to different screens. So doTheActualPrinting() prints to the console. Then I would have another method printToGraphicalUserInterface() which prints to the GUI. So  I do not want to put all this code in the print() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's perfectly fine from the perspective of abstraction. If your concrete class wants to implement its logic in a method with a different name from the interface it implements, and simply call its own method from the interface method, no class using the interface needs to know about that... so the abstraction is preserved.

On the other hand, if classes call `doTheActualPrinting()` instead of calling `print()`, then abstraction is lost.

Comment: So if I wrote the printing logic inside the interface's print() method then it means class Printer doesn't know how to print but completely depends on IPrintSomething to print right?

Comment: In your reply, you said that the abstraction is preserved and I think I understand. So this means that Printer class knows how to print and if it's the only class that knows how it prints then the abstraction is still preserved right?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that users of the abstraction don't have to know how it's implemented. The concrete implementation can do anything, as long as users don't have to know about it.